# Prevent Hibernate from using a column from the predicate in the select clause

Tags: hibernate, hql

Due to performance limitations we gotta optimize database operations and bandwidth. A simple Hibernate HQL query like `from Users u where u.id = ?` generates a SQL sentence such as:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name FROM USERS u where u.id = ?
```

It's pretty dumb that Hibernate repeats in the select clause a field (u.id), that's already present in the predicate (u.id = ?). Does anybody know a straightforward way to prevent this so that the query ends up:

```
SELECT u.name FROM USERS u where u.id = ?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add a select clause to your HQL. Your statement is a synonym for

```
select u.* FROM Users u where u.id = :id
```

If you specify a projection Hibernate will use it.

```
select u.name from Users u where u.id = :id
```

Comment: Unfourtunately our tables have many columns and it'd be a pain to write all the fields. I would like Hibernate to be smarter and realize that it shouldn't query for those fields... No configuration option to prevent that behaviour?

Comment: You need to edit your original post then. Because it does not represent this information